# Year min Value occurs

Tags: filter, find

stupid simple that I dont see an answer for. I want to pull the year for a min ERA ie

Year  ERA
1995  2
1996  3
1997  4

tried

```
spahn[min(spahn$ERA), c("Year")]
spahn[,spahn$Year == min(spahn$ERA)]
spahn[spahn$Age[min(spahn$ERA)]]
```

and I know that tidyverse works

spahn %>%
  filter(ERA == min(ERA)) %>%
  select(Year)

Answer (score 0):

spahn[spahn$ERA==min(spahn$ERA), c("Year")]

that works dunno if it is the best answer though